# ASP.NET Core Environment variable colon in Linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core nested configuration via environment variables is typically done via colon syntax:

`MySettings:SomeSetting=MyNewValue`

How do you do this in Linux? The `export` command rejects the colon? 
eg:

`export MySettings:SomeSetting=MyNewValue`

Errors with

```
bash: export: `MySettings:SomeSetting=MyNewValue': not a valid identifier
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=basicconfiguration#non-prefixed-environment-variables), use a double underscore (`__`)

eg:

```
export MySettings__SomeSetting=MyNewValue
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration#simple-configuration is actually the correct source.

Might've changed since you linked it.

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration&view=aspnetcore-3.1#environment-variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration&view=aspnetcore-3.1#environment-variables) is a direct link to the anchor in the page that covers the `:` & `__` conversion.