# Add environment variables to AWS from appsettings.json C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, environment-variables

In the appsettings.json file of my API project in C#, I have this variable for example:

```
"Recursos":{
   "tipoRecurso":"plasticos",
   "ValorRecurso":"2000",
   "TieneExpedicion":"no"
},
"OtherProperty": "some value"
```

How to add that object property in the environment of AWS? I don't know if this is correct:

[image]

Comment: Where are you deploying app? Lambda or ECS or somewhere else?

Comment: @AnkushJain Elastic beanstalk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40094999/1273882

Answer (score 1):

You need to address every JSON field as a separate environment variable rather than addressing the object as a string of JSON.

| Environment Variable | Field Value |
| --- | --- |
| Recursos__tipoRecurso | plasticos |
| Recursos__ValorRecurso | 2000 |
| Recursos__TieneExpedicion | no |
| OtherProperty | *some value* |

Because `:` can't typically be used as part of an evironment variable's name, you have to use double underscore instead, `__`, to get to the fields of a complex object.

[Ankush's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40094999/1273882) references this.

> **Minor note:** If `Reursos_TieneExpedicion` is a boolean, and not a string, you might need to set the field value to `false`.